# Native iOS logs not showing in Flutter project

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

In my Flutter project, I call native Android code and native iOS code.

From my native Android code, I use `Log.i("tag", "my log")` to log anything I want, and it appears in both the Logcat and the Flutter console.

Now, I want to do the same from my native iOS code. I tried:

```swift
print("my log")
NSLog("my log")
```

but nothing appears anywhere, neither in the Xcode console nor in the Flutter console, which is really annoying when it comes to debugging...

Also, I run my app on an iOS emulator.

So how can I see the log from the native iOS code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> If you build flutter project in Xcode. `print` or `NSLog` you will get the expected output in Xcode console.

[image]

> If you build flutter project in android studio or vs code, you perform `print` or `NSLog` in Xcode will not get you expected output. I‘ve tried.

Maybe [this url will help you](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41133), but i am not sure.

Comment: I'm using Xcode and yes, I've seen that link already, but I'm still stuck unfortunately...

Comment: Were you able to solve this @matteoh ?  I am also facing this issue, all the logs emitted by our native iOS code is not showed in the console, but when you run the same through Xcode, they were shown.   Also we are not facing this problem on Android

Comment: Unfortunately not. Also, apparently, you won't be able to see the log if you run your app on release mode.